# Fixed : Audio recorder missing a callback protector?

Tags: android, c, opensl

According to this:

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/105606/

The bug which would cause the openSL API function 'Destroy' to never return in some instances has been been fixed.

My question is:

Is getting access to this fix just a matter of waiting for an NDK update (which would contain an updated openSL library with the fix) or is it more complex (i.e. like requiring an OS update?)

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find any more info on this?

Comment: yes. it's in the NDK pipeline but also requires a platform update from the manufacturer